# Why are table header and data placed in the same row in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, table-structure

I'm learning about HTML tables. I've got this example:

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

td {
    text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

caption {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animals table</title>
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Animals table</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Animals</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Hippopotamus</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Horse</th>
            <td>Mare</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stallion</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Crocodile</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Chicken</th>
            <td>Hen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rooster</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why are table header (Horse) and data (Mare) placed in the same row, and then another data (Stallion) is placed in another row, e.g.

```html
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Horse</th>
    <td>Mare</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stallion</td>
</tr>
```

When I move the first data tag (Mare) to second row, I get three-column row.

So, what's the intuition behind constructing the table like this? Couldn't it be done some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you want the output to look like?

You might want to read up on how rowspans and colspans work in html.
 [This website](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)  explains very well how to create table layouts, like the one in your example.
`<th rowspan="2">Horse</th>` -> This would mean that Horse takes up 2 blocks downwards. So the next 2 table data (td or th) that you enter would go to the right of that.In this case after Horse you've written Mare and Stallion.
For example if you had a rowspan of 3 it would come out in this way V

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Horse</th>
    <td>Mare</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stallion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Colt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Colspan on the other hand takes up blocks along the row. For the example on your table you can have a colspan of maximum 2 since your table only has 2 columns.Like in the line
`<tr><th colspan="2">Crocodile</th></tr>`
And nothing else will be added to that row.

I really hope this has answered your question and made it more clear.